# Diagnose NIO DatagramChannel read issues under Windows

Tags: java, udp

I'm developing a tool in Java to test RPC communication with an embedded device. We use UDP (which is part of the interface requirements), and have our own mechanism for handling errors and dropped packets.

I have both some client and sever code using `DatagramChannel` for sending/receiving data. They're opened with something that approximates the following, then decorated with a few other `ByteChannel` decorators. I'm using connect, primarily because I like to take advantage of the `read/write` methods, rather than having to use `send/receive`.

```
DatagramChannel channel = 
    DatagramChannel.open(StandardProtocolFamily.INET)
                   .setOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_REUSEADDR, true)
                   .bind(localAddress/localPort)        // SocketAddress
                   .connect(remoteAddress/remotePort); // SocketAddress
channel.configureBlocking(true);
```

The machine on which I'm testing the code is running Win7 64-bit, and has two dedicated adapters, one configured with `localAddress` and the other `remoteAddress`.

When running the tool on this machine (one configured as a server, the other as a client), the client can successfully write data to the channel and the server will then read it from its channel. The server will then write a response to its channel, but the client remains blocked forever, never receiving the data. Watching the exchange in WireShark shows that all the data is received on the client adapter though.

Client:

```
// writer thread
ByteBuffer source;       // contains some data
channel.write(source)    // causes the datagram to be sent to the server

// reader thread
ByteBuffer dest;
channel.read(dest);      // blocks awaiting server's response, which never
                         // arrives.
```

Server:

```
ByteBuffer dest;         // destination for data
channel.read(dest);      // blocks until datagram from client is available
// do some stuff with data found in buffer
ByteBuffer response;
channel.write(response); // causes response datagram to be sent to client
                         // WireShark shows the packet on both adapters.
                         // Server sends, client adapter receives
```

Interestingly, when running the client code on a different machine, and communicating with the target device as a server (instead of my simulated server code), the exchange has no issues. I also gave it a shot using a `DatagramSocket` for the client while still running the `DatagramChannel` on the server, and that seemed to work as well. I called `send` on the socket with a `DatagramPacket` containing the data I would have written to the channel, then `receive` for the response, which blocked until the datagram containing the response arrived.

This seems like an issue with Windows, but I'd like to be sure, and was wondering if I'm missing something. Where would I go next for diagnosing the socket read besides WireShark? I found [SocketSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html), but it doesn't seem to work with Java processes.

Comment: You are bindinging to localAddress and you are setting SO_BROADCAST,  Are you trying to multicast? It's not really clear why you would not be receiving the data; can you post code for both sender / receiver?

Comment: Sorry bout the confusion. A few of the sockets do actually send broadcast datagrams, grabbed that code by accident. I'll update the code sample I've got to remove that. I can't post  the full/send receive code, as it really involves a few decorator classes with some proprietary code. I can include an example of the general process though.

Comment: Hi Robert, I am running into similar issues on Windows. I know this is an old question, but I was wondering if you found the reason this is happening? Any hints would be great as I have been stuck on this for days.